# How to get Particular cells of each row in Google Sheets API

Tags: python, google-sheets-api

I'm using Google Sheets API in python 3
9.5.
I want to get particular cells from each row. Example: I want to get columns A, B, E, G, H, the output should be:

```
[[A1, B1, E1, G1, H1],
[A2, B2, E2, G2, H2], 
.,
.,
.,
[An, Bn, En, Hn, Hn]]
```

Where n is the number of rows a sheet has.

How can I achieve so?

Comment: Can you show what research you did till now? Do you have a code you're working on? As it's currently written, this question seems too broad.

Answer (score 0):

I've come across a similar requirement recently. To solve your requirement, I suggest you to use openpyxl(https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/).
You have to define the source book, destination book, the active sheet and then can do most operations on the active sheet.
The documentation itself is very handy to solve simple issues.

Comment: I'd like to ask for more information, as reading whole columns and writing it to another column is possible with Google Sheets API too. But I'd like to avoid having an extra sheet for this purpose. Any way where I can define my range as such only particular column values of a row are fetched?